# Update specific attributes with DynamoDBMapper in java

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-local

I want to update only the specific attributes of the item using DynamoDBMapper.
For example, I have a User table with attributes viz., id, name, address.

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Users")
public class User {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBGeneratedUuid(DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Address address;

}
```

I want to update only the address attribute and not the other fields (selective update).

I could find a sample example by using UpdateItemSpec but couldn't find it for DynamoDBMapper.
With UpdateItemSpec, I can use withUpdateExpression() to define update expression.
More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.03.html).

Is there any way, to achieve the same with **DynamoDBMapper**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` SaveBehavior

More details on: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-the-savebehavior-configuration-for-the-dynamodbmapper/

Add the SaveBehavior to your `save` operation and keep fields other than `id` and `address` null:

```
mapper.save(user, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES));
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. The only thing is, DynamoDBMapperConfig constructor is deprecated so I used this syntax.
dynamoDBMapper.save(geo, SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES.config()); I have one more doubt, is there any way to load certain attributes while retrieving data from DB using DynamDBMapper?

Comment: It is not working if I want to update a specific field inside the address. Can anyone tell if it is possible at all?